# How to send mocked response data to called through $http call?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a controller that calls a service and sets some variables. I want to test that those variables get set to the response.

My Controller:

```
tankService.getCurrentStats().success(function (response) {
            $scope.stats.tankAvgHours = response.tankAvgHours;
            $scope.stats.stillAvgHours = response.stillAvgHours;
            $scope.stats.stillRemaining = response.stillRemaining;
            $scope.stats.tankRemaining = response.tankRemaining;
            $scope.stats.loaded = true;
    });
```

My Test:

```
...
var STATS_RESPONSE_SUCCESS =
            {
                tankAvgHours:8,
                stillAvgHours:2,
                stillRemaining: 200,
                tankRemaining:50
            };
...

spyOn(tankService, "getCurrentStats").and.callThrough();

...

it('calls service and allocates stats with returned data', function () {

            expect($scope.stats.loaded).toBeFalsy();

            $httpBackend.whenPOST('../services/tanks/RelayTankService.asmx/getCurrentStats').respond(200, $q.when(STATS_RESPONSE_SUCCESS));

            tankService.getCurrentStats()
                .then(function(res){
                    result = res.data.$$state.value;
                });

            $httpBackend.flush();


            expect($scope.stats.tankAvgHours).toEqual(result.tankAvgHours);
            expect($scope.stats.stillAvgHours).toEqual(result.stillAvgHours);
            expect($scope.stats.stillRemaining).toEqual(result.stillRemaining);
            expect($scope.stats.tankRemaining).toEqual(result.tankRemaining);
            expect($scope.stats.loaded).toBeTruthy();

        });
```

The result is that my scope variables are undefined and don't equal my mocked response data. Is it possible to pass the mocked values so I can test the success function correctly populates the variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're testing the controller, there's no need to mock `$http`'s `POST` the way you've done in the test.

You just need to mock the `tankService`'s `getCurrentStats` method.

Assuming that your `tankService`'s `getCurrentStats` method returns a promise, this is how your test must be:

```js
describe('controller: appCtrl', function() {
  var $scope, tankService, appCtrl;

  var response = {
    tankAvgHours: 8,
    stillAvgHours: 2,
    stillRemaining: 200,
    tankRemaining: 50
  };

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _tankService_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    tankService = _tankService_;

    spyOn(tankService, 'getCurrentStats').and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        then: function(successCallback) {
          successCallback(response);
        }
      }
    });

    AdminController = $controller('appCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      tankService: _tankService_
    });
  }));

  describe('appCtrl initialization', function() {
    it('calls service and allocates stats with returned data', function() {
      expect(tankService.getCurrentStats).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect($scope.stats.tankAvgHours).toEqual(response.tankAvgHours);
      expect($scope.stats.stillAvgHours).toEqual(response.stillAvgHours);
      expect($scope.stats.stillRemaining).toEqual(response.stillRemaining);
      expect($scope.stats.tankRemaining).toEqual(response.tankRemaining);
      expect($scope.stats.loaded).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strangely enough I was just reading other posts about testing and it mentioned to remove $httpbackend from controller tests and I was trying to figure this out. I think you have put me on the right track but I'm still getting errors. I switched my controller from .success/.error to .then to match the tests but I am getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tankAvgHours' of undefined

Comment: I got it working, just needed to add data: to the mocked response object.  Thank you so much Siddharth!!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're testing the wrong thing. A service should be responsible for returning the data only. If you want to test the service, then by all means mock the httpbackend and call the service, but then verify the data returned by the service, not the $scope.  If you want to test that your controller calls the service and adds the data to the scope, then you need to create your controller in the test, give it scope that you create, and then test that those variables get added. I didn't test this so the syntax might be off, but this is probably the direction you want to go in.

```
var scope, $httpBackend, controller;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $controller, $rootScope) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
   $httpBackend.whenPOST('../services/tanks/RelayTankService.asmx/getCurrentStats').respond(200, $q.when(STATS_RESPONSE_SUCCESS));
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
     controller = $controller('myController', {
      $scope: scope
    });


  }));
it('calls service and allocates stats with returned data', function () {

            expect(scope.stats.loaded).toBeFalsy();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(scope.stats.tankAvgHours).toEqual(result.tankAvgHours);
            expect(scope.stats.stillAvgHours).toEqual(result.stillAvgHours);
            expect(scope.stats.stillRemaining).toEqual(result.stillRemaining);
            expect(scope.stats.tankRemaining).toEqual(result.tankRemaining);
            expect(scope.stats.loaded).toBeTruthy();

        });
```

Comment: Thanks MorningDew, I'll give it a try. I think i'm pretty much doing what you mentioned  (created controller), the only thing is I passed to the controller $scope:$scope instead of creating a new scope from rootScope and I called the service in the controller test. I think you are saying I shouldn't need to call the service and still be able to check the results from the successful $http call somehow